# MongoDB Spring Data Criteria Not operator

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have following code to search in mongo db using spring data mongodb ( version 1.2.3.RELEASE)

```java
Criteria searchCriteria = Criteria.where("NAME").is("TestName")
        .and("ID").is("TestID").not().and("Age").is("23");
```

I got following query ( without not operator )

```javascript
Query: { "NAME" : "TestName" , "ID" : "TestID", "Age" : "23" }
```

I was expecting following query

```javascript
Query: { "NAME" : "TestName" , "$not" : { "ID" : "TestID"}, "Age" : "23" }
```

What am i doing wrong ?
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I used 'ne' instead.

```
 Criteria searchCriteria = Criteria.where("NAME").is("TestName").and("ID").ne("TestID").and("Age").is("23");
```

Mongo db 'not' is a logical operator.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#not%28%29) the `not()` is affecting **the clause directly following**. That is the `.and("Age").is("23")`. But you probably have to put it before the `is`.

```
Criteria searchCriteria = Criteria.where("NAME").is("TestName").and("ID").not().is("TestID").and("Age").is("23");
```

If this is not working, try using the `andOperator` and the `not().where("ID")` construct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and go following error. `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Invalid query: 'not' can't be used with 'is' - use 'ne' instead.`

Comment: This will teach you not to just use the first answer that you see.
Edit: By you I mean ME.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple items then you can use below query for mongo andOperator(Criteria.where(name).nin(ids))