# Spring-Mongo $ne support : How to use $ne in find by field methods?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongo collection model in Spring-boot as follows

```
@Document
class MyModel{
       @Id
       String id;
       String name;
}
```

I created its repository

```
public interface MyModelRepository extends MongoRepository<MyModel,String> {

}
```

I know I can declare a method inside `MyModelRepository` to find documents having a `name` value equal to some name (let John) using findByField(String name). But if I want all documents that name is not equal to John then I am not sure how can I declare this method in same repository. 
I know I can use @Query or Criteria with MongoTemplate but I am wondering is it possible without @Query or criteria just like findBy equal value. I tried `List<MyModel> findByNotEqualName(String name)` and `List<MyModel> findByNotName(String name)` But both are throwing error. I tried to search it but did not found anything, [Found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353955/mongodb-spring-data-criteria-not-operator) but answer to this question also using Criteria with MongoTemplate.

Comment: You can use `findByNameNot()`

Comment: ohh, Thanks I was doing silly mistake, It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT ($ne)`  operator is suppose to be after `field` name. so correct syntax will be

```java
public interface MyModelRepository extends MongoRepository<MyModel,String> {
         List<MyModel> findByNameNot(String name);
}
```